# Pushing out settings using BES for a BlackBerry 10 App

Tags: blackberry-10

How would I go about making my BlackBerry 10 App compatible with the newly released version of BES? I'd like to support pushing out the application and user settings centrally.

I've scoured the web but have not managed to find anything so far.

Comment: https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/distribute/enterprise_application_distribution.html

Answer (score 1):

We talked to BlackBerry and this is not currently possible with BES10.
It is planned to be implemented in BES12 due late 2014.